# Send data from one mysql table to another mysql table on another server

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I have a server with a database and a table. Upon insert, I want to be able copy the data to another table on another database on another server. I have read intensively on the subject, almost all the articles suggest I use tables with federated engines together with triggers, some others suggest I use replication feature on mysql databases, unfortunately the two servers or databases I am working with have some limitations.

1. There is no replication feature on either of them, it have been disabled and I can't get them to enable it.
2. Both databases can't create tables with federated engines.
3. The client does not want a server script file such as php file checking consistently for new data and sending over to populate the remote database.

However, each server have whitelisted each others IP and communication through a php file is possible between the two servers on either sides. I am able to create triggers on both tables as well. I want to write to the the remote database when ever there is a new data to the local database. There are no foreign key constraints on any of the tables. There is no read latency requirements from when a row is being updated to when it appears on the other server. The updated table does not have a updated timestamp/datetime column. PHP version: 7.1.14. Maria DB Version 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Question:

1. Is there anyway to copy data before or after insert using triggers when the tables are not Federated engine tables(They use other engines, eg. INNO DB) ie... Can triggers have a connection to another server?
2. Is there any other way to copy data to another server without using a federated engine table or replication or using a script that checks for new data every minute or at regular intervals?

Comment: Are both database being written to? Are both databases being read from? Is there any FK constrains on this table? What is the read latency requirements from when a row is being updated to when it appears on the other server? Does the updated table have a updated timestamp/datetime column? Which MariaDB version(s)? Does the data need to be a copy or is a foreign retrieval ok (like Federated(x) and connect)?

Comment: I have updated my question please to answer all the questions